# Break foreign keys into separate lines with loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

At the start of every set of user ids I need a break added. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
for($i=0; $i<count($image); $i++): 
$image[$i]['userid'];
$image[$i]['id'];
endfor;
```

I have no idea where to begin. The output needs to look like this:

id: 2323 user: 12 
id: 2323 user: 13 id: 2323 user: 13 id: 2323 user: 13 
id: 2323 user: 14 id: 2323 user: 14

and it currently looks like this: 
id: 2323 user: 12 
id: 2323 user: 13 id: 2323 user: 13 id: 2323 user: 13 
id: 2323 user: 14 id: 2323 user: 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I show you my solution to the problem I would like to know why there are several users with the same `userid` and `id`? And what is the difference between the id types? This seems weird to me, but without further ado, lets get to it.

I have built a small array of sample data which resembles the output you have described.

```
$users = [
    ['userid' => 2323, 'id' => 12],
    ['userid' => 2323, 'id' => 13],
    ['userid' => 2323, 'id' => 13],
    ['userid' => 2323, 'id' => 13],
    ['userid' => 2323, 'id' => 14],
    ['userid' => 2323, 'id' => 14],
];
```

You can use a variable to indicate what the previous id was and check that each time to determine if a line break should be inserted.

```
$previous = null;

foreach($users as $info) {

    $id     = $info['id'];
    $userid = $info['userid'];

    if(!is_null($previous) && $previous !== $id) {
        echo '<br/>';
    }

    echo "id: {$userid} user: {$id} ";

    $previous = $id;

}
```

This should output the following:

```
id: 2323 user: 12  
id: 2323 user: 13 id: 2323 user: 13 id: 2323 user: 13  
id: 2323 user: 14 id: 2323 user: 14
```

I hope this can help you, happy coding!